# RabbitMQ storm spout cannot connect to existing queue

Tags: java, maven, rabbitmq, apache-storm

I'm trying to build a storm/heron topology with a spout that takes data from a RabbitMQ queue and pass it to a bolt that sends the data to another queue. I'm still learning here, so I trying to build my topology using this project as an example: https://github.com/redink/storm-rabbitmq/tree/master/storm-rabbitmq-test

My topology :

```
public class Topology {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
        QueueDeclaration qd = new ExclusiveQueueWithBinding("rabbit-heron-input", "rabbit-heron-input");
        Scheme scheme = new BasicScheme();
        builder.setSpout( "spout", new AMQPSpout("localhost", 5672, "guest", "guest", "/", qd, scheme));
        builder.setBolt( "rabbitbolt", new EndBolt(),1 )
                .shuffleGrouping("spout");
        Config conf = new Config();
        conf.setDebug(true);
        conf.setNumWorkers(1);
        conf.setMaxSpoutPending(5000);
        try{
            StormSubmitter.submitTopology("testingrabbitheron", conf, builder.createTopology() );
        }
        catch(AlreadyAliveException e){ }
    }
}
```

My pom.xml :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.twitter.heron</groupId>
        <artifactId>heron-storm</artifactId>
        <version>0.14.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.clojars.storm-amqp</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-amqp-spout</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.clojars.pdoctor</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-json</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
        <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>github-releases</id>
        <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/github-releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>clojars.org</id>
        <url>http://clojars.org/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I already have the rabbit-heron-input exchange, which was binded into rabbitmq-heron-input queue with routing key rabbit-heron-input.

Everytime I activate this topology, it always creates a new queue instead of connecting to the existing queue. I tried sending message to the rabbitmq-heron-input queue, but it wasn't detected by the spout. And when I check the RabbitMQ management webpage, it shows a new queue (with name like amq.gen-dWg3pmSodeL7lZ0coMAXNw) which have one connected consumer (which I assume is the spout, since I was working in local environment).

Can anyone help?